# How to add a specific pattern to my loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have a dataframe like that :

[image: dataframe]

And I would like an output like that :

**name1 :**

*mission1 :*

sentences1

sentences2

*mission2 :*

sentences3

**name2 :**

*mission1 :*

sentences4

**name3 :**

*mission1 :*

sentences5

*mission2 :*

sentences6

Here's what I did so far :

```
for name in data.Name.unique():
    print(name)
    print()
    for miss in data.Mission.unique():
        print('  ' + miss)
        print()
        for sentence in data.Phrases[(data.Name == name) & (data.Mission == miss)].tolist():
            print('    ' + sentence)
            print()
```

But unfortunately, there is one little detail not right. This loop give me all the mission by name, even when there is no sentences attached to it.

Here's my output :

**name1 :**

*mission1 :*

sentences1

sentences2

*mission2 :*

sentences3

**name2 :**

*mission1 :*

sentences4

*mission2*  #HERE tthe mission is specified but with no sentences

**name3 :**

*mission1 :*

sentences5

*mission2 :*

sentences6

So, how to tell my loop to not specified the mission when there is no sentences ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally would check if the list of sentences is empty, for example like this:

```py
for name in data.Name.unique():
    print(name)
    print()
    for miss in data.Mission.unique():
        sentences = data.Phrases[(data.Name == name) & (data.Mission == miss)].tolist()
        if sentences:
            print('  ' + miss)
            print()
            for sentence in sentences:
                print('    ' + sentence)
                print()
```

Comment: Oooh I thought about it but my syntax was not right ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Do you know how I could put this output into a txt file or a docx files ?